# JS Typewriter twice on page with different string not working

Tags: javascript, typewriter

I have on 2 different pages of my website a typewriter effect, once with a string in spanish, another location string in english. But I cannot get this to work.

My HTML in one part is the following, this works.

```
<div class="container">    
    <div id="typewriter"></div>                    
</div>
```

The 2nd part where it isnt working is

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="english-typewriter" class="medium-text serif"></div>                    
</div>
```

The JS is the following

```
const spanishInstance = new Typewriter('#typewriter', {
  strings: ['hoteles', 'restaurantes'],
  autoStart: true,
  loop: true,
});

const englishInstance = new Typewriter('#english-typewriter', {
  strings: ['hotels', 'restaurants'],
  autoStart: true,
  loop: true,
});
```

How can I get the English part to work as well?

Source is:

Error showing on the console is

> jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Could not find container element
> at new n (core.js:1:12009)
> at HTMLDocument. (scripts.js:50:25)
> at e (jquery.min.js:2:30158)
> at t (jquery.min.js:2:30460)

The working part of the JS is only this section

```
const spanishInstance = new Typewriter('#typewriter', {
  strings: ['hoteles', 'restaurantes', 'agencias de viaje', 'guía de turistas', 'resorts', 'tour operadores', 'eventos', 'hostales', 'cafés', 'y muchos más'],
  autoStart: true,
  loop: true,
});
```

Comment: We need to see the source of `Typewriter`. Also, are there errors showing up in the console? What are they?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) - include the CDN linked code to the Typewriter

Comment: I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: this.el.appendChild is not a function`. Can you please click [edit] and then `[<>]` snippet editor and make a [mcve] of one working typewriter with commented out second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming https://github.com/tameemsafi/typewriterjs

Here is how, using the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hzfxp2L9/) the author made us

```js
const appES = document.getElementById('appES');
const appEN = document.getElementById('appEN');

const typewriter1 = new Typewriter(appES, {
  loop: true,
  delay: 75,
});

typewriter1
  .pauseFor(1000)
  .typeString('Hoteles')
  .pauseFor(300)
  .deleteChars(10)
  .typeString('Restaurantes <span style="color: #27ae60;">muy</span> interesantes')
  .pauseFor(1000)
  .start();

const typewriter2 = new Typewriter(appEN, {
  loop: true,
  delay: 75,
});

  typewriter2
  .pauseFor(1000)
  .typeString('Hotels')
  .pauseFor(300)
  .deleteChars(10)
  .typeString('<span style="color: #27ae60;">VERY</span> interesting restaurants')
  .pauseFor(1000)
  .start();
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700&display=swap');

.app {
  font-size: 70px;
  line-height: 78px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

strong {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/typewriter-effect@2.20.1/dist/core.js"></script>

<div id="appES" class="app"></div>
<div id="appEN" class="app"></div>
```